# get_post_types() is returning null

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am trying to retrieve the post types and put them into an array with their slug being the index and their label being the value. When I `print_r( get_post_types() );` it returns the proper array with data, but when I try to use it like below, it returns null.

```
function get_posttype_list() {
        $pt_list = [];
        $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ) );

        foreach( $post_types as $pt ) {
            $pt_list[ $pt->name ] = $pt->labels->singular_name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please check [get_post_types](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_types/) documentation. `$output` param's default value is `names` and if you're trying to get `objects` you need to pass `objects` as the 2nd param in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the document [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_types/#user-contributed-notes). You need to return your `$pt_list` array.

```
function get_posttype_list() {
    $pt_list    = array();
    $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ) );

    foreach ( $post_types as $pt ) {
        $pt_list[ $pt->name ] = $pt->labels->singular_name;
    }
    return $pt_list;
}
```